# How to specify text in this search stmt in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have to search with the customername NIXON'S.  But the below statement shows error... I am passing the string value from the UI. So What is the correct format to pass the below searchtext parameter from UI? Please advice....

```
    DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @SearchText = 'NIXON'S';
    SELECT * FROM TBL_CUSTOMERS where StatusId = 1 AND CustomerName LIKE ''%' + 
    @SearchText+'%'';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just replace ' with '' inside your string to escape the special character

```
DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(MAX);
@SearchText = 'NIXON''S';
* FROM B where id = 1 AND record_date LIKE '%' + 
SearchText + '%';
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=592fb661e7e9afa0c6776be869185b2c)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(MAX);
 SET @SearchText = 'NIXON''S';
 SELECT * FROM TBL_CUSTOMERS where StatusId = 1 AND CustomerName LIKE ''%' + 
    @SearchText+'%'';
```

Comment: I found the issue... yes we should give SET  SearchText = 'NIXON''S'; and for like statement '%' + 
    @SearchText+'%' is enough .. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(MAX);
 SET @SearchText = 'NIXON''s';
 PRINT @SearchText
 SELECT * FROM TBL_CUSTOMERS where StatusId = 1 AND CustomerName LIKE '%' 
 + @SearchText+'%';
```